# spring unit test repository save not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, testing, h2

I'm trying to write a unit test, for my spring server.

First it will check if a username is present or not in repository, if not so the username is available, then it will return true, and then I will save that username to my repository and check if available ot not it should return false.

Here is my code:

```
@Test
    public void availableTest() {
        String username="some_username";
        LoginCredential lc=new LoginCredential();
        lc.setUsername(username);
        lc.setPasswordHash("1");
        lc.setSessionID(0);
        assertEquals(true, loginCredentialService.available(username));
        loginCredentialRepository.save(lc);
        assertEquals(false, loginCredentialService.available(username));
    }
```

But for some reason, for the last `assertEquals` it gives me error. So I can say, the data is not being saved in repository, as I have tested my APIs using postman.

**So how this can be resolved?**

I think testing class is properly annotated:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MainApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private LoginCredentialService loginCredentialService;

    @MockBean
    private LoginCredentialRepository loginCredentialRepository;
    ...
```

Comment: Your repository is a mock, so it won't actually save anything in the database

Comment: @EamonScullion for testing purpose how should I save, temporarily ?

Comment: Remove the mock, inject the real LoginCredentialRepository, but you need to configure the database, ensure it runs, etc..

Unit testing with a mock is actually much better, you can verify (with Mockito) in your test that the loginCredentialRepository.save() method is invoked, that should be enough to verify your code can create the record.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad look into integration testing using H2 (in-memory database) that you can use for testing database interactions without mocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged the OP with H2, so I guess you know about In-Memory databases.

If you use the @SpringBootTest annotation, you are writing an integration test, so you'll test the full application as wired by Spring. For efficiency you might want to use an in-memory database for testing instead of a full SQL Server.

You can achieve this by adding H2 database as a test dependency, which will be picked up by Spring Boot for integration test repositories. Then you can inject the actual repository:

```
@Autowired
private LoginCredentialRepository loginCredentialRepository;
```

Additionaly, you can make your test @Transactional. Then every test case will run in a separate transaction, and the transaction will be rolled back after every test, so you don't need to worry about cross-test polution.

If you just want to Unit Test the LoginCredentialService, you need to stub the relevant methods on the repository, e.g.

```
@MockBean
private LoginCredentialRepository loginCredentialRepository;

@Test
public void availableTest1() {
    when(loginCredentialRepository.existByName(username)).thenReturn(true);
    assertEquals(false, loginCredentialService.available(username));
}

@Test
public void availableTest2() {
    when(loginCredentialRepository.existByName(username)).thenReturn(false);
    assertEquals(true, loginCredentialService.available(username));
}
```

You can do this as a pure Mockito test, too, without @SpringBootTest.